# Weird problem in php, one echo works, while the other dosen't in the same block, in PHP

Tags: php

```
....    
else {
              $affiliate->setStatus('D');
              echo "Before load";die;
                if($affiliate->load())
                {
                    echo $affiliate->getUsername();
                    die(($affiliate->getUsername())."Success to load affiliate");
                }
                else
                {
                    $chkaffiliate= new Pap_Api_Affiliate($session);
                    $chkaffiliate->setUsername($_POST['txt_email']);
                    if($chkaffiliate->load())
                    {
                        echo $chkaffiliate->getUsername();
                    }
                    die("Failed to load affiliate");
                }
              die("Failed to process payment,account request declined. <br><br>Please try again using a different email OR Contact our support team to manually approve your account.".$response->error_message);
            }
```

I get the output `Failed to process payment...`that is, the last `die()` in the above code, however I don't get the `Before Load` in the first echo, while both are in the same block. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the `failed to process` is the one you show? Can you add `__LINE__`  to the message to make sure the same message isn't somewhere else as well?

Comment: Are you sure this is your *actual* code?  There is an unconditional `die` on the third line, so I find it difficult to see how you could ever be reaching the last `die`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just not possible.

```
if (something){
   die();
}
else{
   die();
}
```

dies everytime, in any case. Search for other `die("Failed to process payment");` function calls

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line:

```
echo "Before load";die;
```

You die immediately after the echo statement so no other processing will take place!